# Reactjs create new project difference npx and bunx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npx, bun

I tried creating a new project in reactjs with both npx and bunx, but I noticed this:

[image]

[image]

The total size if we look at the bytes or MB even if they differ slightly.

I tried to recreate the projects for a second time, as you can see I still differ in the total size even compared to the same ones.

In the case of npx, there are even fewer files than before.

How come this happens?

Npx:

```
 npx create-react-app my-npx
```

Bunx:

```
 bunx create-react-app my-bun
```

Edit:

Same project name, I used the command:

`diff -rq /Users/nameUser/Desktop/dir/bun/my-app /Users/nameUser/Desktop/dir/npx/my-app`

here are the only differences:

```
Files /Users/nameUser/Desktop/dir/bun/my-app/.DS_Store and 
/Users/nameUser/Desktop/dir/npx/my-app/.DS_Store differ

Files /Users/nameUser/Desktop/dir/bun/my-app/.git/index and 
/Users/nameUser/Desktop/dir/npx/my-app/.git/index differ

Files /Users/nameUser/Desktop/dir/bun/my-app/node_modules/.DS_Store and 
/Users/nameUser/Desktop/dir/npx/my-app/node_modules/.DS_Store differ
```

Comment: They use different package managers which differ in how they manage dependencies. Similarly you can see differences in the resulting files when comparing npm and Yarn.

Comment: @Etheryte: Look at edit, every time I run the commands even for the same ones for example npx I get a different size.